# Scroll bar is shown all wrong

Tags: css

Here is my code:

```
<style>
#defCalTree
    {
        overflow: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

and

```
<div class="defCalTree">
    <div id="treeboxbox_tree" style="width:80%; height:100%;background-color:#f5f5f5;border :1px solid Silver; "></div>
</div>
```

and

to the treeboxbox_tree I attach a dhtmlx tree. But, the scroll bar which is shown I think doesn't refer to the tree. If the tree consists of many items, the div is getting bigger. It should remain the same size, and by using the scroll we will get to every item. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `class="defCalTree"` doesn't match 
`#defCalTree`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the height of the `#defCalTree` div. As it is now, it is growing in size to wrap its contents, which is the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

In css you are using # which is selector for id and in html you are using class. so how your css will work. is this your problem or some thing else check it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to either:

Amend `<div class="defCalTree">` to `<div id="defCalTree">`

OR

amend `#defCalTree` to `.defCalTree`